# How to make a link between what was inserted and where it came from

Tags: sql-server, join, cross-reference

I am inserting into a table like

**Items (itemId, name)** where id is an identity.

from a table like this

**RawData (name, description, otherinfo)**  where multiple names are possible. Such as "A" coming up three times, lets say it looks like this

```
A,Desc1,x
A,Desc1,y
A,Desc2,z
B,Desc1,x
```

After I insert into Items, I get 3 entries for "A", lets say

```
1,A
2,A
3,A
4,B
```

Now I want to insert into a table called
**Descriptions (DescriptionId, ItemId, description)**

I cannot accurately provide SQL that filles itemId 1,2,3 because joining **Items** back to **RawData** doesn't provide a 1:1

I want to do

```
INSERT INTO Descriptions
SELECT ItemId, description
FROM RawData R
INNER JOIN Items I ON I.name = R.name
```

What I want is to join it and have it be like (last 2 columns are Items)

```
A,Desc1,x,1,A
A,Desc1,y,2,A
A,Desc2,z,3,A
B,Desc1,x,4,B
```

what I get instead is

```
A,Desc1,x,1,A
A,Desc1,x,1,A
A,Desc1,x,1,A
A,Desc1,y,2,A
A,Desc1,y,2,A
A,Desc1,y,2,A
A,Desc2,z,3,A
A,Desc2,z,3,A
A,Desc2,z,3,A
B,Desc1,x,4,B
```

One solution I thought of is to add an identity to RawData and then include that when I insert into Items to help me link the tables back to how they were. Then when I am done delete that column. But that seems like a very hacky way.

Another solution I can think of is SQL like

```
INSERT INTO Descriptions
SELECT DISTINCT ItemId, description
FROM RawData R
INNER JOIN Items I ON I.name = R.name
```

but this doesnt work in my real-world example. I start off with 200 items in RawData and end up with 215 after the join, so clear a 1:1 isn't happening

I am looking for generic approaches to the solution of my problem. Not so much solutions that work for this specific example (Thats why the example is so basic)

Comment: So, first of all, how can three different items have the same name ? There's your problem.... When you perform the join, this violation of uniqueness in what you are using as a key is causing a Cartesian product in the resultset

Comment: Yes, that is the nature of the data. They are 4 unique items but 3 have the same name.

Comment: Then the data is corrupt, or you are not understanding it properly. If it is possible for three different items to have the same value for an attribute, that attribute CANNOT be used as a key value to find and reference a single row in the table. Is that not clear to you?

Comment: i.e. you cannot identify and locate a single bob smith if there are 5 people named bob smith.

Comment: Data is not corrupt. I understand what I am doing is trying to use a key that is not unique, and thats why its finding multiple matches. What I am after is for a solution to get to my end result. Ideas and approaches that dont incorporate temporarily modifying the Items table to add a unique key to join on

Comment: Then you are out of luck. There is no way to uniquely identify a single record when multiple records exist with the same values. You could just randomly pick one, but then the result is unquestionably corrupt as the id that gets generated is not indicative of the data, it could be one of the multiples one time you do it, and another different one the next time.

Comment: One possible way would be to read in the RawData and maintain a cursor, and then insert into the Item table and then Description table one by one. This is not really a preferably option, which is why I am open to more ideas.

Comment: That will not guarantee correct data, as the set of matching values might be different each time yo perform this operation, causing whatever algorithm you settle on to match a different record the next time you execute it. No this is just a bad database design, and you need to fix it, or, if that's not possible, learn to accept and deal with the consequences.

Comment: At least in OP `col1 + col3` construct a key. Try to use natural key.

Comment: I mean, just think about this logically, if the raw data says you inserted an "A", which "A" was inserted?  If you are really serious that there are three different entities all named A, then how is it possible to know with any certainty which A was actually inserted? Fix it, or accept that your data will remain forever ignorant about differentiating between them.

Comment: It doesnt matter which A, because it has multiple matches. In my "What I want table" you can see that the order was 1,2,3,4  but it doesnt matter if it was 1,3,2,4  ...3,2,1,4 ...2,3,1,4, etc because the definition of the Item table is ambiguous. `A,Desc1,x` can be Item1, 2, 3 -- none of that matters

Comment: To fix it you need to add something in both the items table and the rawdata table that will allow you uniquely identify an Item.  Either that or figure out how to populate the rawdata table with th3e id instead of the name.

Comment: If "it doesn't matter which A" then there are not three different As, there is only one. and then the question is why are there three rows in item table named "A" ?

Comment: I didnt clarify enough, It doesnt matter which ItemId is assigned to which A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to populate `Descriptions` table matching your raw data with newly populated `Items` for the time of import you could add a column to `Items` table which will uniquely identify a row and drop it after populating `Descriptions`.

Let's say in your case the uniqueness would be on `(name, description, otherinfo)`.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/170f84/1)** to show you how it works.

**Creating tables**

```
CREATE TABLE items(itemid int primary key auto_increment, name text);
CREATE TABLE descriptions(descriptionid int primary key auto_increment, itemid int, description text);
CREATE TABLE rawdata(name text, description text, otherinfo text);
```

**Adding temporary column**

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD COLUMN tmp_unique text;
```

**Populating items**

```
INSERT INTO items (name, tmp_unique)
  SELECT name, concat(description, '#', otherinfo)
  FROM rawdata;
```

**Populating descriptions**

```
INSERT INTO descriptions (itemid, description)
  SELECT itemid, description
  FROM rawdata r
  INNER JOIN items i ON
    r.name = i.name
    AND concat(r.description, '#', r.otherinfo) = i.tmp_unique;
```

**Dropping temporary column**

```
ALTER TABLE items DROP COLUMN tmp_unique;
```

*Note: If speed is of your concern then in your case you can create two unique columns and put description and otherinfo from rawdata separately and then join by both of those columns while populating descriptions.*

Comment: This is probably the best way to go, although im wary of it because the Items table will have 1000s of records before I insert into it.

Comment: Good luck using different approach. Looping would be much slower my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of this so figured I'd add it as a potential solution.

Add Identity column "ID" to RawData.

Before inserting into Items:

```
DECLARE @StartId INT = ( SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Items'));
```

Then use Identity INSERT for `Items` using `@StartId + ID` of RawData;

Then later on you can use

```
SELECT @StartId+ID as ItemId, description
FROM RawData R
```